# Updating stored procedure Entity framework throw "verify that the FunctionImport name is unique" error

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I am using EF v4.3 and I have a problem in updating a stored procedure.

I the Model Browser I selected the stored procedure I want to update (it has a Function Import and a Complex type that I want to update).

I right clicked and selected Add Function Import. The usual window opens.

My first problem is that EF does not automatically pick up the fact that there is already a complex type defined since the "return a Collection Of" radio button is set to None instead of Complex.

Anyway, I selected the correct complex type and pressed the "Update" button. The stored procedure box is populated with the correct complex type and the rows that need to be changed are marked as "Update" in the action column.

I pressed OK and a message box is displayed with the error message "Verify that the FunctionImport name is Unique".

I can solve this problem by deleting the Function Import but I do not want to do it every time. Why is the update not working? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Michele

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. You actually need to go to the Function Import you need to modify and update from that object. No need to delete and add again!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a screenshot to show what you need to do, either delete the existing one or update per OP's comment:

[image]